# Des personnes qui « sont, se mettent en/sur la ligne » implique-t-il obligatoirement d'être de côté ?

Tags: sens, usage, locutions

Sur [*Usito*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/ligne), on trouve une définition de « ligne » :

> Suite de personnes, de choses alignées les unes à côté des autres.

Avec entre autres les syntagmes suivants :

> *Être, se mettre en ligne, sur une ligne.*

Peut-on confirmer qu'avec des personnes, ces syntagmes impliqueraient obligatoirement qu'elles sont les unes à côté des autres et peut-on trouver des exemples qui le démontrent ? S'agit-il d'une exception à un [emploi déconseillé d'un emprunt](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22151/les-emprunts-a-langlais/emprunts-semantiques/emploi-deconseille-de-lemprunt-ligne) ?

Comment: Je suis pas sûr de comprendre la question. Quand tu dis "obligatoirement les unes à coté des autres", tu veux dire par opposition aux unes derrière les autre ? Une ligne peut être dans toutes les directions (avant/arrière ou droite/gauche), pas besoin d'un emprunt pour justifier ça

Comment: Il semble que l'emploi déconseillé le plus proche se rapporte à une file d'attente comme dans l'anglicisme "attendre en ligne". "Etre / se mettre en ligne" n'est pour sa part ni une exception ni incorrect.

Comment: On ne va pas relancer le débat, mais il serait peut-être temps de se rendre compte que les gens écrivent des commentaires parce que leur remarque concerne un aspect subsidiaire de la question... c'est tout à fait légitime. Et si vous écrivez des questions qui en contiennent en réalité deux et demi, il faut s'attendre à des commentaires.

Comment: En quoi la question référencée qui détaille le sens de ligne, rang, rangée, etc. ne vous éclaire-t-elle pas sur ce que veut dire une "ligne" dans "se mettre en ligne" ? En d'autres termes, pourquoi "ligne" aurait-il un autre sens dans "se mettre en ligne" que son sens habituel ?

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Je ne sais pas si je dois prendre toutes ces remarques pour moi. En tout cas mes commentaires ne visaient pas à rabaisser la question ou être désagréable envers l'auteur. Désolé d'avoir provoqué cela. Je vais tâcher de mettre plus d'empathie dans mes réponses à l'avenir !

Answer (score 1):

> Une ligne peut être dans toutes les directions (avant/arrière ou
> droite/gauche), pas besoin d'un emprunt pour justifier ça.
> ([Teleporting Goat](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53558/des-personnes-qui-sont-se-mettent-en-sur-la-ligne-implique-t-il-obligatoire#comment113946_53558))

Answer (score 0):

> Il semble que l'emploi déconseillé le plus proche se rapporte à une
> file d'attente comme dans l'anglicisme "attendre en ligne". "Etre / se
> mettre en ligne" n'est pour sa part ni une exception ni incorrect.
> ([Guillaume31](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53558/des-personnes-qui-sont-se-mettent-en-sur-la-ligne-implique-t-il-obligatoire/53564#comment113948_53558))

Answer (score 0):

*En ligne* peut aussi signifier *sur l'internet*, à la suite de l'expression *être en ligne* qui voulait dire *être sur la ligne téléphonique*, et peut-être par calque de l'Anglais *online* aussi.